# how to save a content then post it

Tags: mysql, ajax

I'm currently working with grapesjs open source code from github but I have a problem to save it to mysql and the post it, I ask some guy who did it but still not quite understand.

here's the code

```
cmdm.add('save-database', {
    run: function(em, sender){
      sender.set('active', true);
      var InnerHTML = this.frameEl.contentDocument.activeElement.innerHTML;
      $.post("/components/save/component", {html: InnerHTML}, function(result){
        // code here
      });
    },
  });
```

What can code I should put there, an ajax or??

Comment: What are you trying to save? What have you tried already?

Comment: i'm trying to save the content